# How to resolve a SHA1 hash mismatch?

Tags: homebrew, sha1

> Error: SHA1 mismatch
>   Expected: 85f620a26aabf6a934c44ca40a9799af0952f863
>   Actual: db0e50d3ba8957eeb7879b1eaa03b0f004e121a7
>   Archive: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/cloog-0.18.0.tar.gz
>   (To retry an incomplete download, remove the file above.)

I couldn't find the file so how do I fix this?

Comment: Delete the file and try again?

Comment: again I couldn't find the file to delete

Comment: `/Library/Caches/Homebrew/cloog-0.18.0.tar.gz`?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried updating homebrew. Update to the latest and then try your command again, its the first thing to try before looking further

```
brew update
```

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck at this & tried:

- `yarn update`
- `yarn cleanup`
- deleted the old file from `/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/`
- company VPN could be a problem for some:

  - paste the URL (from where brew is downloading) in a browser to see if you need to by-pass any company warning etc.

**solution:**

- the problem was that I was only deleting the latest problem file via finder... there could've been more/other similarly named filed
- instead of deleting the file from finder, just do:
  `rm /Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/528fccab152aa17857e73f54f268d413bf94e22188c0e4ff17a6c497d2783b88--package-name@1-1.1.1.bottle_manifest.json`